# Building requirejs and angularjs application

Tags: angularjs, backbone.js, requirejs, js-amd, r.js

Found a good tutorial post about `requirejs and backbonejs` [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/a-requirejs-backbone-and-bower-starter-template/) and the updated scripts [here](https://github.com/NETTUTS/RequireJS-and-Backbone-Starter). In this article he build all script files to a single JavaScript including views and models. Like this, I need to build my `angularjs and requirejs` app to a single js file written using [this post](http://www.startersquad.com/blog/angularjs-requirejs/) and [this script](https://github.com/StarterSquad/startersquad.github.com/tree/master/examples/angularjs-requirejs-2).

Can anyone help me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even styles and images (via mixins) may be included, using RequireJs plugins line require-less and require-css, but this is another story).

Meanwhile, checkout this demo [repository](https://github.com/shustariov-andrey/angularjs-requirejs) - I just updated it. It now builds text files into bundle as well.

Comment: Can you update the repository to use latest angular js with dependencies like ngRoute?

Comment: @devo Updated to version 1.2.8